# Multiple mod_rewrite rules generating redirect loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using mod_rewrite, I want to have two rules:

- rewrite .htm and .html requests to .php
- remove .php extension

so that`http://example.com/page.html` calls `http://example.com/page` 
and that `http://example.com/page.php` calls `http://example.com/page`

I tried this which breaks when I introduce the .html rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php [R,NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [R=301, L]
```

I'm rather new to mod_rewrite; could anyone show me how to correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteCond` conditions are too weak to catch a rewrite loop; they only check that the path being rewritten is asking for a concrete file or directory.

Yes, your first rewrite rule should stop looping, but the conditions only apply to the first `RewriteRule`; your second `RewriteRule` is unconditional. Each `RewriteRule` has its own `RewriteCond`-s.

(The first rule can still loop because the input can contain `.htm` multiple times; at each rewrite round you remove one `.htm` by not including the part which contains a match for `.htm` in the rewrite.)

Your second `RewriteRule` is a relative rewrite. If this is in a `.htaccess` file or a `<Directory>` configuration (a per-directory context), you need `RewriteBase`. Otherwise the rewrite will take `http://example.com/foo` and generate a URL of the form `http://example.com/path/to/docroot/foo.php`, which will only work if your setup is hacked to accept `/path/to/docroot/` as a URL synonymous with `/`.